# SQL sum of count of names, group by year

Tags: sql

really hoping someone can help me as I'm rubbish at SQL!

I have a table that looks as follows, and I need to show the most popular name for each year...

```
+---------+----+-----------+------+-----------+-----+
|UNIQUE_ID|YEAR|     COUNTY|GENDER|       NAME|COUNT|
+---------+----+-----------+------+-----------+-----+
|        1|2013|ST LAWRENCE|     M|      GAVIN|    9|
|        2|2013|ST LAWRENCE|     M|       LEVI|    9|
|        3|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|      LOGAN|   44|
|        4|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|     HUDSON|   49|
|        5|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|    GABRIEL|   50|
|        6|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|   THEODORE|   51|
|        7|2013|      KINGS|     F|      ELIZA|   16|
|        8|2013|      KINGS|     F|  MADELEINE|   16|
|        9|2013|      KINGS|     F|       ZARA|   16|
|       10|2013|      KINGS|     F|      DAISY|   16|
|       11|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|   JONATHAN|   51|
|       12|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|CHRISTOPHER|   52|
|       13|2013|    SUFFOLK|     M|       LUKE|   49|
|       14|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|    JACKSON|   53|
|       15|2013|    SUFFOLK|     M|    JACKSON|   49|
|       16|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|     JOSHUA|   53|
|       17|2013|   NEW YORK|     M|      AIDEN|   53|
|       18|2013|    SUFFOLK|     M|    BRANDON|   50|
|       19|2013|      KINGS|     F|       JUDY|   16|
|       20|2013|ST LAWRENCE|     M|      MASON|    8|
+---------+----+-----------+------+-----------+-----+
```

... Goes on for thousands of rows...

I know I have to do a sum of count and a group by year, but nothing I try seems to work.

The output should look something like...

```
+----+--------+-----------+
|YEAR|TOTAL   |MOST_POPULAR|
+----+--------+-----------+
|2016|   12419|      GAVIN|
|2015|   22119|       LEVI|
|2014|   44113|      LOGAN|
|2013|   12349|     HUDSON|
|2012|   15024|    GABRIEL|
|2011|   55311|   THEODORE|
|2010|   13446|      ELIZA|
|2009|   12346|  MADELEINE|
|2008|   13456|       ZARA|
|2007|   21126|      DAISY|
|2006|   13451|   JONATHAN|
|2005|   52241|CHRISTOPHER|
|2004|   14923|       LUKE|
+----+-----+-----------+
```

Please help!

Comment: what;s your dbms? like Oracle,SQL Server,MySQL,Postgres etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help -

```
SELECT YEAR,TOTAL, NAME AS MOST_POPULAR
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR,NAME,TOTAL, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) AS RNK
    FROM (
            SELECT YEAR,SUM(CNT) AS TOTAL, NAME
            FROM TAB1
            GROUP BY YEAR,NAME
            ORDER BY 2 DESC
        )
    ) WHERE RNK = 1
  ORDER BY YEAR DESC;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for pointing out, the query is now updated

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if the following code works for you:

```
SELECT year, total, Name AS 'Most_popular'
FROM tablename
WHERE name IN (SELECT year, name, MAX(count) 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY year, name)
ORDER BY YEAR DESC
```